# Azure Devops pipeline not picking the variable group

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a build pipeline which tries to

1. build a docker image for .net core api project
2. push the image to Azure container registry

For the above two tasks i have created 2 docker file tasks and it works as expected, only issue is i have linked certain variable groups to this pipeline but it does not picks the values and has my local appsettings.json values.

i am using classic approach of creating a build pipeline.

Can any one shed some light to this issue.

```html
# Variable Group 'Azure Blob Storage - NPD - API' was defined in the Variables tab
# Variable Group 'Azure Credentials - NPD -API' was defined in the Variables tab
# Variable Group 'Azure Credentials - NPD -Service' was defined in the Variables tab
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/MigrateTo.NetCore6
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: FileTransform@1
    displayName: 'File Transform: '
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      folderPath: API
      fileType: json
      targetFiles: appsettings.json
  - task: Docker@1
    displayName: Build image for Api
    inputs:
      azureSubscriptionEndpoint: aa01dc83-bf31-477f-abf2-f9d461ca43d0
      azureContainerRegistry: coinianpd.azurecr.io
      command: build
      dockerFile: CORE_API_Dockerfile
      imageName: $(Build.Repository.Name)-Api:latest
      buildContext: '**'
  - task: Docker@1
    displayName: Push image for Api
    inputs:
      azureSubscriptionEndpoint: aa01dc83-bf31-477f-abf2-f9d461ca43d0
      azureContainerRegistry: abc.azurecr.io
      command: Push an image
      imageName: $(Build.Repository.Name)-Api:latest
      buildContext: '**'
```

Docker File

```html
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["x.CORE.API/COINIA.CORE.API.csproj", "x.CORE.API/"]
COPY ["x.SERVICES/COINIA.SERVICES.csproj", "x.SERVICES/"]
COPY ["x.COMMON/COINIA.COMMON.csproj", "x.COMMON/"]
COPY ["Framework/Framework.csproj", "Framework/"]
COPY ["x.EXTRACTOR/x.EXTRACTOR.csproj", "x.EXTRACTOR/"]
RUN dotnet restore "x.CORE.API/x.CORE.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/x.CORE.API"
RUN dotnet build "x.CORE.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "x.CORE.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "x.CORE.API.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you share the related actions in your pipeline

Comment: can you share your docker file and build-pipeline yaml?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier modified my questuion above to include yaml and docker file

Comment: Is Task FileTransform not overriding group variables for appsettings?
in the Variables tab did you select the scope for the correct stage?

Comment: @LeonardoOliveira i cannot see any option to set  scope for the correct stage either while linking an variable group or after that also

Comment: which variable are you no able to access, I can only see the defauly variables being used and where do you want to use it, typically the group name should be included under - variables

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier i am using classic pipelines , and this is the yaml that got generated which i provided. The variable groups that i want are added in comments at the top.You mean in yaml it should look like below.

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/MigrateTo.NetCore6
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
    variables:
  - group: 'Azure Blob Storage - NPD - API'
  - group: 'Azure Credentials - NPD -API'
  - group: 'Azure Credentials - NPD -Service'

Comment: can you share log task FileTransform?

Comment: @LeonardoOliveira

Substituting value on key AzureDownloadEnvironmentName with (string) value: QA
Substituting value on key IsDownloadFilesFromAzure with (boolean) value: true
JSON variable substitution applied successfully.
Finishing: File Transform:

Comment: if these two variables were transformed,
was for dotnet to use these values. I do not see a problem.